# How to print Twitter API request reply?

Tags: php, twitter

I want to print all the tweets from the reply. What am I missing?

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);

/** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=%23twitter';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest();

foreach ($response->statuses as $tweet) {
    echo $tweet->text;
}
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/projects/twitter/twitter-api-php/index.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/projects/twitter/twitter-api-php/index.php on line 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `performRequest()` method returns a JSON string, not an array, so you need to decode it `$array = json_decode($response, true);`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use:

```
`echo $response;`
```

or instead:

`echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
            ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->performRequest();`

but I recommend using the first approach.